# Metric Given by Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $L_p([a,b];\mathbb{R}) = \{f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R} | f$ is Riemann-integrable $\}$. I want to prove that 
$$
d_p(f,g) = \left(\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}
$$
defines a metric in $L_p([a,b],\mathbb{R}).$

Given $f,g$ integrable I easily see that $d_p(f,g)$ exists and that $d_p(f,f)=0$ and $d_p(f,g) = d_p(g,f)$. I also proved the triangle inequality  by proving the Hölder inequality for positive real functions. I'm just stuck in the condition $f\neq g \to d_p(f,g)>0$. For simplicity I'm assuming $f \neq 0$ and trying to prove $\int |f|^p \neq 0$.

I know that $f\ge 0$ implies $\int f \ge 0$ but I don't see how to get the strict inequality. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually the space should be altered a bit, since $f =0 $ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ would deduce that $\int_a^b |f|^p = 0$.

Comment: Will continuos functions work?

Comment: Yes, that would avoid the possibility that $\int |f - g|^p = 0$ but $f \neq g$, since $\int |f|^p = 0$ and $f$ be continuous would deduce that $f \equiv 0$. This claim could be proved by contradiction.

Comment: So the usual notation $L_p$ are used for spaces of continuous functions?

Comment: Not exactly. Actually $L$ stands for "Lebesgue" integration. Generally $R$ would be used for Riemann integrals. For continuous functions, try $C$, or $C_p$ to indicate the metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prove it because it is not true. If$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=a\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then $d_p(f,0)=0$, but $f\neq0$. The function $d_p$ is a [pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space), but not a metric.

Comment: If I change the set for continuous functions then it'll be a metric? Or is the problem in the defining function per se?

Comment: @AnalyticHarmony Yes, if you restrict $d_p$ to the space $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$, then it becomes a metric.